# Why doesn't Intl.DateTimeFormat work in IE browser

Tags: javascript

I have this JS function:

```
var TodayDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(en-US, { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }).format(Date.now())
```

the output is:

Chrome : April 19, 2020

Edge : April 19, 2020

Firefox = April 19, 2020

but in IE(Internet Explorer) is not work at all why?

Comment: Also see [*Internet Explorer 11 computed timezone bug*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914911/internet-explorer-11-computed-timezone-bug).

Answer (score 2):

It only works in Internet Explorer 11, no earlier version than that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

[image]

[toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) should give the same result and is available on IE 5.5+

```js
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }).format(Date.now()) 
console.log(dateTimeFormat)

const localeDateString = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })
console.log(localeDateString)
```

Comment: Well what is the solution?

Comment: Updated post with an alternative

Comment: IE < 11 doesn't support [language tags or options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility), they're ignored.