# Best method to detect if the browser Time Zone is Nepal UTC +5:45 NPT

Tags: javascript

What is the best method on browser-side to detect the Nepal Time-Zone?

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/nepal

The code should work both in the newest and older browsers such as Iexplorer.

```
zone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

What value should I expect for NEPAL and does the above code work in IE too? Would it be better to use jstimezonedetect library instead?

Comment: Have you tried with `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`?

Comment: @savageGoat It may be a good question, but not for Stack Overflow: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour], [no attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Ok I added my code line

Comment: Please don't modify your question after it was answered. Now, you've copied the answer into your question and the answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that,  do this or that,  never right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone === 'Asia/Katmandu'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if this code works also in the old web-browsers such as  IE 11

Comment: @Tom Should work. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) says all the pieces here are available in IE11.

Comment: Here it says its not working..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914911/internet-explorer-11-computed-timezone-bug

Comment: @Tom The answer to that question seems to also answer your question here. (Also, if the answer doesn't work, then why accept it?)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.getElementById('guess').innerText = moment.tz.guess();
</script>
```